# Optional class members in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to specify type-safe optional members in Typescript classes?

That is, something like...

```
class Foo {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c: number;
}

....

foo = new Foo();
...
if (foo.a !== undefined) { ... (access foo.a in a type-safe string manner) ... }
```

In case you are familiar with OCaml/F#, I am looking for something like 'string option'.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following works in TypeScript 3.x:

```
class Foo {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
  c: number = 123;
}
```

Note that you need to initialise any members that are not optional (either inline as shown or in the constructor).

Comment: Is there any way to avoid optional properties being defined at all? (`{a: 'asdf', b: 'nada' }` instead of `{a: 'asdf', b: 'nada', c: undefined }`

Comment: Also I get `Supplied characters do not match any signature of call target` on TypeScript Playground and in VS [see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20string%2C%20c%3A%20string)%0D%0A%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test('foo'%2C%20'bar')%3B)

Comment: This answer is outdated or at least promote thing that doesn't work by default since TypeScript 2.7.

Comment: This answer is outdated or at least promote thing that doesn't work by default since TypeScript 2.7.
Since TS 2.7 you would get
`Property 'c' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`
Which is correct answer to your code that states that `Foo#c` must be defined but it is not safety initialized.

Comment: The answer has been updated and works with the latest TypeScript versions 

Answer (score 15):

Optional class properties was added as a feature in Typescript 2.0.

In this example, property **b** is optional:

```
class Bar {
  a: number;
  b?: number;
}
```

[Typescript 2.0 release notes - Optional class properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#optional-class-properties)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Revised according to your feedback :)

Comment: Interesting. I'm using TS 4 and it gives me unexpected token error if I add ? in a class definition. Interface seems to allow it tough.

Answer (score 12):

In some use cases you can accomplish it with [*Parameter properties*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html):

```
class Test {
    constructor(public a: string, public b: string, public c?: string)
    {
    }
}

var test = new Test('foo', 'bar');
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20a%3A%20string%2C%20public%20b%3A%20string%2C%20public%20c%3F%3A%20string)%0D%0A%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test('foo'%2C%20'bar')%3B)

Answer (score 2):

Optional properties and methods can now be declared in classes, similar to what is already permitted in interfaces:

```
class Bar {
    a: number;
    b?: number;
    f() {
        return 1;
    }
    g?(): number;  // Body of optional method can be omitted
    h?() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

When compiled in --strictNullChecks mode, optional properties and methods automatically have undefined included in their type. Thus, the b property above is of type number | undefined and the g method above is of type (() => number) | undefined. Type guards can be used to strip away the undefined part of the type:

```
function test(x: Bar) {
    x.a;  // number
    x.b;  // number | undefined
    x.f;  // () => number
    x.g;  // (() => number) | undefined
    let f1 = x.f();            // number
    let g1 = x.g && x.g();     // number | undefined
    let g2 = x.g ? x.g() : 0;  // number
}
```

[Optional class properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#optional-class-properties)