# Eliminating type ambiguity in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have code along the lines of this:

```
function defaultIt(s: MaybeString): string {
  if (typeof s.content === "string") {
    return s.content;
  }

  return "";
}

class MaybeString {
  content: string|void;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this is about as type-safe as you can get; any possible input that fits `MaybeString` will result in a string. However, TypeScript gives me an error: `Type 'string | void' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

How can I get TypeScript to recognize that I've removed ambiguity by checking the type?

Thanks!

Comment: Admittedly, I've only been using Typescript for a few months, but does it makes sense to type `content` as `string|void`? This is a "union type" correct? So what you're saying by doing that is the `content` property ONLY has the properties that are common between `string` and `void` (and since `void` has no properties at all, `string|void` is basically the same thing as `void`). Are you trying to say the `content` property is optional and may not have a value?

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood. I thought it was kind of like a "Maybe" sort of thing. Is there a way to say it can be *either* a string or void?

Comment: I deleted my answer b/c it was about optional properties on interfaces. But you basically don't need to do anything special (regarding typescript declarations) if the class property is optional. This was the conclusion I came to after you pointed out my mistake, and it's backed up by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18916914/398606).

Comment: I suppose my question is more general, but I was trying to simplify it. What if I want to make it either a string or a function, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can use additional variable:

```
var temp:string|void = s.content;

if (typeof temp === "string") {
   return temp;
}
```

[sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20defaultIt(s%3A%20MaybeString)%3A%20string%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20var%20temp%3Astring%7Cvoid%20%3D%20s.content%3B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20temp%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20temp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MaybeString%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20content%3A%20string%7Cvoid%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Or cast to string:

```
if (typeof s.content === "string") {
   return <string>s.content;
}
```

[sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20defaultIt(s%3A%20MaybeString)%3A%20string%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20s.content%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cstring%3Es.content%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MaybeString%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20content%3A%20string%7Cvoid%3B%0D%0A%7D)

For classes you can use `instanceOf` function, see [this article](http://rostacik.net/2015/05/27/how-to-get-type-of-object-in-typescript-when-using-union-types-and-type-guards-for-multiple-types-of-function-parameter-or-variable/) for details

Comment: It's a little weird that you can do that, actually, considering `s.content` is already of type `string|void`