# Property "employee "does not exist on type "Department"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making a beginner website and everything was good so far but I have a strange problem now.

When type ng serve --open in the node.js console to start the site on the localhost
I receive this message ->

> ERROR in src/app/department-detail/department-detail.component.ts(59,32): error TS2339: Property 'employee' does not exist on type 'Department'

My code is that:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Department } from '../department';

import { DepartmentService }  from '../department.service';

import { Employee } from '../employee';
import { EmployeeService }  from '../employee.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-department-detail',
  templateUrl: './department-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./department-detail.component.css']
})
export class DepartmentDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  department : Department ;
  employees: Employee[];
  emp: Employee;
  average:number=1;


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private departmentService: DepartmentService, private location: Location,private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDepartment();

    this.getEmployees();
  }
  getDepartment(): void{
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.departmentService.getDepartment(id).subscribe(department => this.department = department)
  }

  goBack(): void{
    this.location.back();
  }
  save(): void {
   this.departmentService.updateDepartment(this.department);
   this.goBack();
 }

 getEmployees(): void {
   this.employeeService.getEmployees().
   subscribe(employees => this.employees = employees);
 }

 Select(firstname:string){
   firstname = firstname.trim();
   if(!firstname){return;}
   this.employeeService.getEmployeeByName(firstname).subscribe(Employee => this.emp = Employee);
 }

 Delete():void{
   this.emp = null;
   this.average = 1;
 }
 Show():void{
   this.Select(this.department.employee); // this cant be true
   this.average = null;
 }


}
```

The problem is in the last

> Show function

If I delete employee and save and then add it again the side works but otherwise it does not.

> This is my department component.

```
export class Department{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    location: string;
    menId: number;
    static Id:number = 1;

    constructor(name: string,location: string) {
        this.id = Department.Id++;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.menId = 0;

    }

}
```

I am not sure whether I should add a property of type Employee in the Department component.

Comment: yes you need to add one

Comment: Well, I did but it did not work. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `Department` class you will notice that it, in fact, doesn't have the *employee* property. You should add one like this:

```
export class Department{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    location: string;
    menId: number;
    static Id:number = 1;
    employee: string;        // New employee property, type based on the Show method signature

    constructor(name: string,location: string) {
        this.id = Department.Id++;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.menId = 0;

    }

}
```

After adding the property you might get another error, this time in the application runtime, saying that `firstname is undefined`. If you get this error, it is thrown by the `Select` method, in which you first try to trim the name and then you check whether it's defined or non-empty. To prevent the error you should simply swap the first and the second lines of the `Select` method so they look like this:

```
if(!firstname){ return; }
firstname = firstname.trim();
```

Comment: I get this error now: 

ERROR in src/app/departments.ts(3,14): error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; name: string; location: string; menId: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Department[]'.
  Type '{ id: number; name: string; location: string; menId: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Department'.
    Property 'employee' is missing in type '{ id: number; name: string; location: string; menId: number; }'.

Comment: That's because you tried to instantiate the Department class somewhere else in the code, and those objects are now missing a property you've just added. You should add the missing property to all the objects of class Department in your departments.ts file, or change the employee: string to employee?: string. The question mark means that the property is optional. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916104/optional-class-members-in-typescript

Comment: Oh, I found my other mistake. With what you gave me here it worked. Thanks a lot. It was a pain in my ass for a while.