# typescript class field question mark

Tags: typescript

As title. I know that a question mark in object fields means that it's not required in this type. But I don't know what it means when it's used in defining a class, to be specific I saw this in the source code:

```
export class MockServer {
  private server?: Server;
...
```

Could anyone explain why we need it here? Does it mean the class doesn't have this property to be this type? But this explanation seems to be strange.

Comment: Yes, they are [optional class properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#optional-class-properties).

Comment: @jcalz: Could you share how did you find it? I didn't really want to waste you expert's time but I use some comb. of the words in my title to Google and found nothing.

Comment: I have a bunch of the TypeScript handbook in my browser history; in this case I searched for `site:stackoverflow.com typescript class property "question mark"` and `site:stackoverflow.com typescript class property optional` in Google and found various results here, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916104/optional-class-members-in-typescript).

Comment: @jcalz: Thanks! I actually did the same thing learning python in the past. All heros endure pains.